# jquery transit opacity animation conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-transit

I have an element that I want to move and the, half way through the move, start fading out. By the time the move is complete, it has 0 opacity. I am using the transit library to make these animations smoother. Opacity on its own works. Move on its own works, but the 2 do not play nice together. where am i going wrong?

```
$(function() {
    $("#go").click(
        function(){
        $("#block").transition({y:'90px', queue:false}, 2000);
        $("#block").transition({ x: '90px',queue:false }, 2000 );
        $("#block").transition({ opacity: 0 ,queue:false , delay:1000 }, 1000 );
    });
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bastiat/5844Q/

Comment: Use `.animate({opacity: 0, ...})` instead of `.transition({opacity: 0, ...})`

Comment: @Mathias `transition()` is almost identical to `animate()`. It's a third party plugin that adds extra features to the native `animate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using CSS transitions and just triggering them with jquery: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5844Q/2/)

CSS

```
 div {
     background-color:yellow;
     width:100px;
     border:1px solid blue;
     position:absolute;
     x:50px;
     -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
     -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
     -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
     -o-transition: all .8s ease;
     transition: all .8s ease;
     margin-left: 0px;
 }
```

JQuery

```
$("#go").click(function () {       
$("#block").css('margin-left', '90px').css('opacity', '0');                   
});
```

JQuery (if you want the opacity to fade after it moves over): [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5844Q/3/)

```
$("#go").click(function () {
    $("#block").css('margin-left', '90px')
    .delay(800)
        .queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('opacity', '0');
        next();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To actually use the transit plugin to solve this problem, you need to add them to the same `transition()` call.

```
$(function() {
    $("#go").click(
function(){
    $("#block").transition({ x: '90px', opacity: 0, queue:false }, 2000 );
    //$("#block").transition({ opacity: 0 ,queue:false , delay:1000 }, 1000 );
});
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qngmwmo2/